# Log out goes to black screen

Tags: debian

I've just updated my Debian to Jessie from Wheezy. I have auto login for my user and after logging out it goes to black screen. After clicking "Screen lock" nothing happens.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that problem I changed the ATI driver from AMD/ATI Proprietary Driver fglrx which is now incompatible with the GNOME desktop, as it does not support the EGL interface in Debian 8. After update it is recommended to use the free radeon driver instead, so I changed to radeon driver and it fixed my problem.

More info:
https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary
https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of this issue before, if you are able to SSH back into the machine I'd check `service gdm3 status` and `dmesg` for any hints. It could also be power save disabling your monitor, this would be the most likely explanation on a laptop and in that case `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` may wake the screen again.

Comment: This is not on laptop. I'm not the only one with the issue: http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=2622. Another problem is that there is no way back from the black screen.

Comment: @mazikwyry Oh, sorry I didn't realize you're using KDE. The issue you linked to was present in an early version of Jessie back in 2013 and describes two different symptoms, one where the screen goes completely blank and the other where a text cursor is visible in the top left corner. I need more information to solve this, can you please update your question to include which graphics card you have (if possible also which driver you use) and the last few lines of dmesg?